# Upgrade or reinstall from 18.04.6 on i386 archtecture

Tags: system-installation

I am running Ubuntu 18.04.6LTS on "i386" architecture, and since this is no longer supported I would like to upgrade to the latest version of LTS Ubuntu. Current OS is 32-bit, however it looks like my laptop can run 64-bit. How can I upgrade or re-install Ubuntu to get the latest version?

I can't find any instructions for this situation on the Ubuntu website. Please keep in mind that I am not at all tech-savvy, and it took me most of the morning just to figure out the information above. If you are able to help me with a response, please imagine that you are trying to explain this to your grandmother.  Thanks!

Comment: Your current version (18.04.6LTS on "i386") is supported until next year. However, if you need to upgrade, you will have to reinstall. Please check that your system can run 64-bit Linux with a "live" CD. In any case, I would recommend you to _wait three more months_ and install Ubuntu 22.04 64-bit.

Comment: You didn't say if you're running a desktop or server system as that matters. You can re-install a desktop of a different release over an existing system (re-use existing partitions without format) and it'll cause your system to be upgraded to the new system without touching user files, settings etc (unless system-wide as these are replaced with new defaults)  and it'll re-install your *manually installed* packages automatically (*if available in Ubuntu repositories for the new release*) which allows change of architecture (ie. *i386* [32-bit] to *amd64* [64-bit]) but that's desktop

Answer (score 2):

You cannot "upgrade" from 32-bit to 64-bit. Just like you cannot "upgrade" from a bicycle to a sedan. Different chassis, no upgrade path.

You must *install* 64-bit Ubuntu on that hardware. You installed Ubuntu before, now you follow that process again. Download the 64-bit .iso, make a Live USB, run the installer. You remember doing all that before with 32-bit. Time to do it again with 64-bit.

Backup your data on to some other media before installing, since installing risks complete erasure of all data.